# How to correctly install dokku - with or without sudo?

Tags: dokku

I'm learning dokku right now for simple web deployment. Offical install instructions state this command:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/progrium/dokku/v0.3.12/bootstrap.sh | sudo DOKKU_TAG=v0.3.12 bash
```

I'm not a devop or admin, but as far as I understand this line, it performs all bootstrapping and installation under the `root` account, thanks to `sudo`. So dokku will be checked out into a directory with `root` access rights, and all additional directories like `/var/lib/dokku/` will also have `root` access rights.

The problem is - all articles across the internet about dokku instructs to execute `dokku` command or do dokku-related actions without `sudo`. For example, instructions about this `dokku` database plugin, https://github.com/krisrang/dokku-mariadb, instructs to install it via:

```
cd /var/lib/dokku/plugins
git clone https://github.com/krisrang/dokku-mariadb mariadb
dokku plugins-install
```

This is not working, since `/var/lib/dokku/plugins` have `root` access rights and `git clone` will fail with `acces denied`. It's hard to be a non-admin nowadays, but maybe someone will hint what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to install dokku some other way, or all dokku-related tutorials across internet assume that I'm executing them under `root` (which is, by my limited admin knowledge, highly not recommended for security reasons).

Comment: `Sudo-dokku` sounds like an awesome name for a puzzle game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run those three commands as `sudo`:

```
sudo su -
```

The dokku binary will run code as the dokku user even if you execute as root. So it should be fine to run that as is. Once you are the sudo user, just run the install instructions listed in your question. Hope my answer helps ! :)

I also contacted them as they mentioned:

> In the future, we'll have a method to install plugins directly with a
>   dokku command

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, you need to run it as root. A traditional way to install a program without root-privileges is to [download the source and compile it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges), which can be done by running:

> git clone https://github.com/progrium/dokku.git
>
> make
>
> make install

Dokku's makefile depends on apt-get, which requires root access to run.

I'm not familiar with dokku or dokku-mariadb, but I think the author of dokku-mariadb also assumes root access.

Answer (score 0):

For people running into the question on wether its fine to install through root user (on fresh created VMs as per the guide), try checking this Github issue:
https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/961

Since the commands related to dokku are prefixed with `#` rather than `$`, it means that its not necessary to run them from non-root user. It also makes writing suddo unnecessary (and form my experience counterproductive).